# How to store php blog post in mysql database with images and other html text format?

Tags: php, mysql, regex, web, mysqli

I'm working on my php blog project.How can I store images from a blog post to a directory?
Blog post may contain strong, italic, web link,list, images and so on.

(I'm php beginner. Thanks in advance.)

Comment: Your Question is too wide and you are asking for full ready made code so that's why -1 for that..!

Comment: i just need procedure to know not code.

Comment: Post anything what you have tried and what CMS are you using for your blog?? WordPress etc???

Comment: You can use PHP `DOM` : http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: Take in mind that you're not entitled to answers that showcase any more effort than your question.

Comment: Its on raw php. Is it mandatory to show what i've tried? If you don't wanna help its fine but please don't blame. I haven't post my school project here @UmairShahYousafzai

Comment: @unreleased : I aplogize where are my manners..of course I want to help..let me tell you what you are trying to do is called Data Scrapping..!

Comment: You can use following PHP DOM HTML Parser Library to do it : http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks I'll try it. @UmairShahYousafzai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here let me show you how you can do it :

## BY USING

**PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser :**

LINK : http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

**Sample Code For Downloading All Images From The Link :**

**Note :** Following code will download all the images present at the URL given in the code.

```
<?php
// Make sure to include the library php file
include('simple_html_dom.php');

//URL To Download Images From
$url = "http://www.google.com/"

// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html($url);

// Find all images 
$i=1;
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) { 
$url = $element->src;
$img = "/my_folder/image_".$i.".png";
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
$i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: @unreleased : Here I posted an answer for you.You know I like to help everyone possibly I can But I like to only help the motivated people,the ones who comes with some progress so try better next time..There are lots of tutorials available at web which can teach you to do it in a very simple way..! Besides If my answer helped so please make sure to mark the answer as accepted so that this question can be considered solved..!

Comment: Would anyone please explain the -1?